# Simple require validation inside Custom Component input

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, validation

I have multiple components and each having some input, select and other form elements. This all elements developed using template driven form.

But previously it was developed not in component wise, so we were able to check form status. Now as we have divided everything by component but validation we are not able to get it.

I have two questions.

1. For getting child component form elements to parent component, I am using **ControlValueAccessor**, is this correct way to do it ? In my child component i have multiple form controls like input, select and other.
2. Simple validations like required on input element, its not working inside child component. What should i do ?

This is [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sHCMAX0bXvWFAd3fA8xn) which mostly demonstrates what i wanted to achieve.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `

  <h1>Child</h1>
  <input [ngModel]="firstName" (ngModelChange)="firstSet($event)" required>
  <input [ngModel]="lastName" (ngModelChange)="lastSet($event)" required>  <!-- required validation is not working -->
  `,
  providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: Child, multi: true}
  ]
})

export class Child implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {

  private firstName: string,
  private lastName: string;

  fn: (value: any) => void;

  constructor(){

  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    console.log("write value");
    console.log(value);
    if(value){
      this.firstName = value.firstName;
      this.lastName = value.lastName;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this.fn = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  firstSet(v: string){
    this.firstName = v;

    this.fn({
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName
    });
  }

  lastSet(v: string){
    this.lastName = v;

    this.fn({
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName
    });
  }
}
```

If you find wrong way please mention which is correct way to do it ?

Note: Please suggest solution which works on **Template Driven Form.** and i forgot to mention i am using Angular 2.4.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wouldn't use [**Reactive Forms**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html) - they are pretty much designed for validation.

You can also mix and match , you aren't locked into using Template Driven Forms just because you are using ngModel.

You can utilise Reactive Forms just for validation.

*component.ts*

```
form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb : FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      'firstName' : ['', Validators.required],
      'lastName' : ['', Validators.required]
    })

  }

  hasError(n: string){
    return this.form.get(n).hasError('required') && this.form.get(n).touched;
  }
```

template.html

```
<h1>Child</h1>
  <input [ngModel]="firstName" name="firstName"  [formControl]="form.get('firstName')" required>
  <div *ngIf="hasError('firstName')">This field is required</div>
  <input [ngModel]="lastName" name="lastName"  [formControl]="form.get('lastName')" required>  <!-- required validation is not working -->
  <div *ngIf="hasError('lastName')">This field is required</div>
```

### Plunkr found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/r21ZZMWTU4cxky7BOj2m?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But currently there are around 30 components and they all are developed using template driven way, so i dont think i can suggest to change every form reactive way.
So i need to find solution for template driven form only.